replacing zero values in a time series data
I would like to know how to fill up or replace the zero values in a column(e.g. consumption) with the same parameter value (e.g. consumtion) based on the total hourly average value of that parameter(e.g. consumption) in a time series data.
so, i have a datafreame something like this:
date                               consumption              hour
2017-09-18 13:00:00                    0                    13
2017-09-18 14:00:00                    5                    14
2017-09-18 15:00:00                    8                    15
2017-09-18 16:00:00                    0                    16
2017-09-18 17:00:00                    10                   17
...............................................................
................................................................
2022-01-01 05:00:00                    0                    5
2022-01-01 06:00:00                    16                   6

what i want, In the consumption column where there is zero values, i would like to replace them based on the hourly average value (for example: my hourly average value from the data is like below)
hour             consumption
0                  1.5
1                  2.6
2                  2.9
3                  2.7
4                  1.8
5                  2.8
6                  5.8
7                  7.8
8                  12.8
9                  15.2
10                 15.8
11                 15.6
12                 16.1
13                 12.5
14                 12.9
15                 10.5
16                 9.4
17                 9.1
18                 13.5
19                 13.2
20                 12.7
21                 5.3
22                 4.2
23                 2.5

so this will be my expacted outcome
date                               consumption              hour
2017-09-18 13:00:00                    12.5                 13
2017-09-18 14:00:00                    5                    14
2017-09-18 15:00:00                    8                    15
2017-09-18 16:00:00                    0                    16
2017-09-18 17:00:00                    10                   17
...............................................................
................................................................
2022-01-01 05:00:00                    2.8                  5
2022-01-01 06:00:00                    16                   6

I tried to replace the zero values in my cosumption column with THE HOURLY AVERAGE data
df['consumption'].replace(0, df.groupby(by='hour')['consumption'].mean())


Assuming the first dataframe is df and the second (with the hourly average data) is df_hourly, you can use this approach:
df.loc[df["consumption"] == 0, "consumption"] = df.merge(
    df_hourly.rename(columns={"consumption": "consumption_avg"}), on="hour", how="left"
)["consumption_avg"]

                 date  consumption  hour
0 2017-09-18 13:00:00         12.5    13
1 2017-09-18 14:00:00          5.0    14
2 2017-09-18 15:00:00          8.0    15
3 2017-09-18 16:00:00          9.4    16
4 2017-09-18 17:00:00         10.0    17
5 2022-01-01 05:00:00          2.8     5
6 2022-01-01 06:00:00         16.0     6

